# Laravel fresh install not loading Bootstrap on auxiliary default views

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I just completed freshly installing Laravel on a VPS, relocated the public folder to the public_html folder and redirected all associated files to point to here.

Going to the default domain loads bootstrap correct, and the welcome page displays with the bootstrap formatting, I auto-generated the login/register auth pages and navigating to those doesn't utilize bootstrap formatting, logging the error that `http://web.com/js/app.js ERROR 404: Not Found`

Like I said, this is fresh install, except everything that was in the public folder was migrated to public_html and I edited the index.php accordingly. I've been trying to search up other people with the same issue on here except they all seem to have issues with bootstrap generally while the error with bootstrap only occurs on other pages for me, making their solutions useless. Although anyone familiar with Laravel will already know what it looks like, here's the app.blade.php file that is used to format the auxiliary pages.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('../js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('../css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd already done a bit of editing with the routing to the JS and CSS links, adding ../ to see if that'd help as opposed to the auto-generated js/app.js but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Downvoted with no explanation or link to a thread I've missed, cheers.

Comment: Seems okay. You fully made sure that the file exists? What are the permissions for the public/js/app.js file?

Comment: As I said I've removed the public folder and moved all it's contents to the public/html, and update the index.php file to navigate correctly, still nothing.

Comment: In this case i assume that your index.php and js folder are in the same level, right ?